# React/Redux Doesn't Update State Properly and Can't Be Used in Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, connect

I am new to React and Redux and have been following the official Redux docs Todo List example https://redux.js.org/basics/example and recently changed my code to follow the presentational/container components structure. I have tried many different ways of moving the API call, but often times the weights object in the state is showing as undefined (likely because it's trying to be used before the actual API call is made, but I can't figure out how to change the API call from where it is now).

Here are the files:

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getWeights = () => dispatch => {
  axios.get('/api/weights')
  .then(res => 
    dispatch({
      type: 'GET_WEIGHTS',
      payload: res.data
    })
  )
}

export const setShownCategory = category => ({
  type: 'SET_SHOWN_CATEGORY',
  category
})

export const Categories = {
  SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
  SHOW_ACCESSORIES: 'SHOW_ACCESSORIES',
  SHOW_BARBELLS: 'SHOW_BARBELLS',
  SHOW_DUMBBELLS: 'SHOW_DUMBBELLS',
  SHOW_PLATES: 'SHOW_PLATES',
  SHOW_RACKS: 'SHOW_RACKS',
  SHOW_OTHER: 'SHOW_OTHER'
}
```

reducers/weights.js

```
const initialState = {weights: []}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_WEIGHTS':
      return {
        ...state,
        weights: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

components/Items/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import CategoryBar from './CategoryBar'

import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getWeights } from '../../actions'
import WeightItems from './WeightItems';

class Items extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.getWeights();
  }

  render() {
    const { weights } = this.props.weights;
    return (
      <div>
         <Typography variant="h4">Browse</Typography>
         <div>
           <CategoryBar />
         </div>
         <WeightItems weights={weights} />
       </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  weights: state.weights
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getWeights }
)(Items)
```

components/Items/WeightItems.js

```
import React from 'react'

import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Item from './Item'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  items: {
    display: 'flex',
    margin: 'auto',
  }
})

const WeightItems = ({ weights }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.items} container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center" spacing={3}>
      {weights.map(weight => <Item key={weight.id} weight={weight} />)}
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default WeightItems
```

components/Items/Item.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const Item = ({ weight }) => {
  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <Paper>{weight.title}</Paper>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default Item
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleWare = [thunk];

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
);

export default store;
```

Currently, I call the API in the components/Items/index.js component by importing the corresponding dispatch action and using connect(), however, instead of doing this and passing the weights in, I need to be able to call the API somewhere else and render the VisibleWeights component, based on the filter selected from a different component (I'm not showing as it's working properly and updating the state properly, but can definitely add if it needs to be shown for context).

containers/VisibleWeights.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Categories } from '../actions'
import WeightItems from '../components/Items/WeightItems'

const getVisibleWeights = (weights, category) => {
  console.log(weights, category)
  switch(category) {
    case Categories.SHOW_ACCESSORIES:
      return weights.filter(weight => weight.category === 'Accessories')
    case Categories.SHOW_BARBELLS:
      return weights.filter(weight => weight.category === 'Barbells')
    case Categories.SHOW_DUMBBELLS:
      return weights.filter(weight => weight.category === 'Dumbbells')
    case Categories.SHOW_PLATES:
      return weights.filter(weight => weight.category === 'Plates')
    case Categories.SHOW_RACKS:
      return weights.filter(weight => weight.category === 'Racks')
    case Categories.SHOW_OTHER:
      return weights.filter(weight => weight.category === 'Other')
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  weights: getVisibleWeights(state.weights, state.shownCategory)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(WeightItems)
```

Please let me know if I can add any other code or comments. I've been working on getting this little thing right for the past two days, and can not figure out what needs to be changed to make this work properly. I know the API is being called correctly, but don't know how the components need to be changed to be able to display it properly. **When I try to call the  component instead of the  component, I get the error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' **

Comment: in `components/Items/index.js` you are destructuring `weights` as an object, but  initial state you are declaring it as empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are declaring `weights` as an empty array `[]` in initial state in `reducers/weights.js`

And you are destructuring it as as below

```
const { weights } = this.props.weights;
```

as weights as per your declaration is `undefined` you are getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

so try changing it as per your exact requirement

Make sure that all your code works even with no data beacause the whole component gets rendered before the API call, so either handle the components to render with empty data and make sure your code dont beak before you get the API data

As per your code it think `wights` is Array of Objects so making the following change wont break your application i think

**File**: `components/Items/index.js`

In `render` function change the following line

```
const { weights } = this.props.weights;
```

To

```
const { weights = [] } = this.props;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate the quick response! However, this change still doesn't allow the VisibleWeights component to be displayed instead of the WeightItems component. I'm not getting the undefined TypeError from the code I've displayed, but do get it when replacing the WeightItems component with VisibleWeights in components/Items/index.js

Comment: can you create a codesandbox of the app for better debugging

Comment: yes, I'll try and put one together sometime today, thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow, in the middle of creating the code sandbox I realized that the returned object I was mapping through had a child component with the same name that contained each array of data from the database. Even without showing the sandbox, you led me to the answer, and I appreciate it!